# Стоит ли хранить фрагменты разметки в xml или лучше использовать строки с кусками html?

Tags: xml

Есть ли смысл хранить в базе данных фрагменты разметки, например комментарии, в формате xml, и каждый раз, при запросе применять xsl преобразования, или это слишком слишком скажется на производительности и лучше сразу преобразовывать в кусок html строки. От пользователя поступает xml с тегами которые разворачиваются в более сложную html разметку.

Answer (score 1):

У меня несколько противоположное мнение.
По моему мнению, хранить в БД цельный HTML как-то не логично. Не гибко. В БД должны быть сериализованные данные. А вдруг, к примеру, вам нужно будет изменить разворачиваемый HTML (изменить алгоритм преобразования начального XML в HTML?. Поедет вся ваша разметка, и придется пересчитывать и перезаписывать результаты по всей базе).
Не думаю, что такое преобразование затратно по времени или ресурсоемко. Если уж будет слишком частое обращение к алгоритму преобразования, никто не мешает конечный результат положить в кэш.

Comment: Тем фактом, что шаблон разметки может поменяться я и руководствовался задавая вопрос. С другой стороны, изменение схемы преобразования, происходит несопоставимо реже чем запросы к бд. Вообщем, это выбор между более гибким и чуть более производительным решениями.Спасибо за ответы. Буду тестить...

Answer (score 0):

Если действие выполняется более одного раза - то лучше конечно сохранить результат. Тем более ни что не мешает сохранять и xml и html.

Answer (score -1):

У меня есть стойкое ощущение что у вас там что-то очень неправильное в архитектуре. Может вам просто нужен хороший шаблонизатор.

Comment: Ну так xslt и выступает как шаблонизатор. Задача сводится к обработке и сохранению разметки поступающей от пользователя. После фильтрации, некоторые специальные теги и атрибуты преобразовываются в более сложную разметку, которая может содержать, не разрешённые, для прямого ввода пользователям, элементы. К примеру, так конструируются цитаты, спойлеры и т.д. Если тут присутствует архитектурная ошибка, пните меня, я начинающий)

Comment: Принципиальных ошибок нету, но от использования xslt в пайтоне меня просто коробит. В базе фрагменты хранить бессмыслен это точно.

Я бы реализовал свой парсер который преобразует входящую разметку в дерево, которое в дальнейшем обрабатывается требуемым образом и сериализуеться в необходимую разметку.

Собственно такой подход даст высокую гибкость и возможность расширения за счет новых типов нод, ну и отсутствие богопротивного xslt. К тому же при таком подходе (Нода дерева является классом) нет необходимости держать фрагменты в виде отдельных сущностей.